# How TCP socket handles data designated for send

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, boost-asio

I am working on a design of [ASIO](http://think-async.com/) TCP socket based client / server system.The requirement is as follows:

- TCP Server sends continuously(as long as the client socket connection is open) varying in size chunks of data to the client
- Client sockets reads that data continuously as long as a user doesn't terminate the client side process.

In this scenario it may happen that the client consumes the data much slower than the frequency of the data being sent by the server.And the server may send quite large chunks(10-100kb).

And this leads me to ask, maybe, a simple question for experienced network developers,but a detailed and clear answer to which I haven't been able to find by searching SO and the web:
What happens to the data in the time span between the moment it has been sent by the server socket, and till it is read by the client socket?
The closest info on this topic that I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721002/boostasio-sending-data-faster-than-receiving-over-tcp-or-how-to-disable-buffe).

As I understand, there is some buffering happening to the data being sent?
Where does it happen and how can it be controlled by developer?

Comment: Read about [the TCP flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Flow_control).

Comment: Also remember that typical packets send over Ethernet are around 1500 bytes. Sending data larger than that will cause it to be fragmented.

Comment: It's buffered in the network stack, either on the client or server, depending on where the backlog is.

Comment: Finally, if your data is more packet-oriented than streaming, then consider using UDP. Possibly with a simple layer on top of the raw UDP packages for some TCP-like reliability. Or perhaps something like [SCTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol).

Comment: If you want a quick, dirty explanation - the receiver will ask to send it N bytes of data and sender will send only those. If buffer gets filled on receiver side, the sender won't send more data.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal no, I don't want "a quck and dirty explanation".I want a   concise  answer.

Comment: @MichaelIvanov then read about 'Sliding window protocol'